# Having Issue on Using Boolean With Simple Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/byk309j8/) and let me know why this bug is happening during the validation of two type of input selections?

Technically, what is happening is if user not select either of checkboxes and Select options and push the submit button the error message shows up and the `validRequest` boolean stays in `false`. Now if user ONLY select  the checkboxes the situation is same the `validRequest` boolean is `false` and error message shows up **BUT** if user forgets to select the checkboxes and only selects from the list the `validateQuery()` validates the `validRequest` as `True` and then now error message and alert message pops up!

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

```js
$(function () {
    var validRequest = false;

    function validateQuery() {

        var selectedDoll = $('input:checkbox[name=doll]');
        if ($(selectedDoll).is(':checked')) {
            validRequest = true;
            $('#err').html('');
        } else {
            validRequest = false;
            $('#err').html('Some Thing Wrong!');
        }

        var selectedIcecream = $("#icecream").val();
        if (selectedIcecream == 0) {
            validRequest = false;
           $('#err').html('Some Thing Wrong!');
        } else {
            validRequest = true;
            $('#err').html('');
        }
    }

    $("#isValid").on("click", function () {
        validateQuery();
        if(validRequest){ alert('Ready To Go');}
            console.log(validRequest);
    });

});
```

```css
#err{color:red;}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="doll" value="cat" />Cats
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="doll" value="dog" />Dogs
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="doll" value="bird" />Birds
    <br />
    <br />
    <select id="icecream">
        <option value="0">Select From List</option>
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
    </select>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" id="isValid" value="Submit now" />
</p>
<p>
    <div id="err"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: you have two independent conditions and a single flag, yet want validation only if both are true.  You either need to restructure everything to be a nested (or compound) condition, or else have two separate flags and then check the truthness of both. You can do this with two separate variables, an array (and then count length) or increment `validRequest` and check if it's >=0. Just depends on how you want to show the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:  http://jsfiddle.net/byk309j8/7/

The problem was that you had 2 independent if statements while you must have only one. Also you were checking if the select box is empty `== 0` instead of not empty `!== 0`

```
$(function () {
var validRequest = false;

function validateQuery() {

    var selectedDoll = $('input:checkbox[name=doll]');
    var selectedIcecream = $("#icecream").val();

    // checkbox is not checked, but select is
    if ($(selectedDoll).is(':checked') && selectedIcecream == 0) {
         validRequest = false;
        $('#err').html('select not selected');
    } else if ($(selectedDoll).is(':checked') == false && selectedIcecream != 0) {
       validRequest = false;
        $('#err').html('checkbox not checked');
    } else if ($(selectedDoll).is(':checked') == false || selectedIcecream == 0) {
         validRequest = false;
        $('#err').html('checkbox not checked or select not selected');
    } else {
          validRequest = true;
         $('#err').html('');
    }
}

$("#isValid").on("click", function () {
    validateQuery();
    if(validRequest){ alert('Ready To Go');}
        console.log(validRequest);
});
});

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="doll" value="cat" />Cats
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="doll" value="dog" />Dogs
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="doll" value="bird" />Birds
<br />
<br />
<select id="icecream">
    <option value="0">Select From List</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
    <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
</select>
    </div>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" id="isValid" value="Submit now" />
   </p>
      <p>
<div id="err"></div>
  </p>

#err{color:red;}
```

Comment: Thanks Stanimir, this is working now but I got another question here? In case of generating different Error Message like `Please Specify The Checkbox` and `Please Select From The List` for each type of error. How we can handle them in only one `if()` condition?

Comment: Ah, that's different. Let me rewrite the example.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, try now.